# Change Style of GeoJSON circle marker by feature property value

Tags: colors, leaflet, geojson, markers

I have a GeoJSON feature collection of points assigned to lat/long coordinates, and i want to be able to assign them variable colors based on the value of a specific feature property. 
I have seen examples creating creating chloropleths for different layers, but have not seen an example for imported points. 
Using the layout, this is my getcolor function for values within a certain range of a specific feature property

```
$.getJSON("LRV_NoUTEP.geojson", function (data) {
  // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
  function getColor(d) {
    return d < 0 ? "#a6cee3" : d < -50 ? "#1F62FF" : "#001C5C";
  }
```

This is my geoJSON layer creating the points, and also creating a popup with all of the information, which works fine on its own.

```
  L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 10,
        fillOpacity: 0.85,
        color: getColor(feature.properties.anomalymgals),
      });
      //var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, marker) {
      marker.bindPopup(
        "<b> Latitude: </b>" + feature.properties.lat + "<br/>" +
          "<b> Longitude: </b>" + feature.properties.long + "<br/>" +
          "<b> Easting: </b>" + feature.properties.easting + "<br/>" +
          "<b> Northing: </b>" + feature.properties.northing + "<br/>" +
          "<b> Elevation_meters: </b>" + feature.properties.elev + "<br/>" +
          "<b> Anomoly_mgals: </b>" +  feature.properties.anomalymgals
      );
    },
  }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

edited

```
      <title>Leaflet </title>

<link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "comcat.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/iconfamily=Material+Icons|Merriweather:400,400italic,700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,700"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet-src.js">
```

```
 </head>

<body>

 <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script>
 //load the image
var mymap = new L.map('map', {
layers: [
    L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '',
    id: '',
})
],
}).setView([44, -114.5], 9);
```

I can't seem to get the circle marker to return with new values, or anything at all when i introduce the getcolor function. What am I doing wrong? or is there a problem with formatting the way the function is is called on.

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/2EVBxtYK8Y5g7XX8), at least for two colours (the third one doesn't show because of how the ternary operators are chained, and because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)).

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I reformatted it to yours, but it doesn't seem like it is able to load the points from my data file. I think the issue might be with how my map is loaded, not quite sure. The difference from your example was the layers: [  . I will post mine down below. Or is there a specific link in the index that is necessary to perform some of those procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my problem is, when plugging all of my information into plunker, I am able to do it successfully. I am fairly new to using plunker, but it seems when i attempt to input the information into an existing html document, it seems to have a problem. I guess this turns into a general issue, where you are able to create a webpage, with a section just for a map followed by text. How should i go about doing this?